# Convert Dictionary with Differing Lengths to DataFRame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a dictionary to a DataFrame in python, but the other answers on stack are for slightly different purposes and I can't seem to do it.

```
have <- {0: [1, 2], 1: [1]}
want <- ['cluster' = [0, 0, 1], 'value' = [1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: The fact that you do not understand the question is not reason for downvoting people.

Comment: Check my answer, maybe you will understand now. Regards.

Comment: The cafe I was at was closing as I asked this, I planned to add more. However, Luis answered it correctly. I was looking to essentially flatten the dictionary so that I could create a dataframe and then a csv which was in a tidy format (one row per value).

Comment: @spazznolo, I'm glad to help you out mate. Kindly accept the answer then. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cluster = []
value = []
for i,j in my_dict.items():
    for k in j:
        cluster.append(i)
        value.append(k)
```

Output

```
cluster # [0, 0, 1]
value # [1, 2, 1]
```